# remove bullets from wordpress woocommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress

My problem is that there are bulletins around my pictures under the third step "order info", and i have no clue how to get rid of them.

You may have to place something into the cart for it to work.

I've tried messing with some of the woocommerce code files php/css/etc, but am ultimately stumped on where to look for the next steps.

http://www.consciouscope.com/checkout/ is my website.

[woocommerce_checkout] is the template ill likely need to edit.
Thank you so much in advance.
JS.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to remove bullets from checkout

```
.row.cart-table.cart_item li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    .row.cart-table-top li {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

Comment: You can add this in your css file

Answer (score -1):

```
.row.cart-table.cart_item li {
      list-style: none !important;
    }

    .row.cart-table-top li {
      list-style: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `!important`, unless you have *no other option left*. It's a really dirty hack and shouldnt be recommended.